Color problem in disqus in Django and Tailwind
I tried to use disqus in my django project:
<div>
    <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script>
        /**
         *  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
         *  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables    */
        var disqus_config = function () {
        this.page.url = "{{ request.path }}";  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
        this.page.identifier = "{{ news.id }}"; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
        };
        (function () { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
            var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
            s.src = 'https://site-name.disqus.com/embed.js';
            s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
            (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
        })();
    </script>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments
        powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
</div>

But I got this error:
Uncaught Error: parseColor received unparseable color: oklch(0.7464770.0216264.436)
I'm using "daisyui" in project and apparently "disqus" interferes with it. daisyui is a tailwind plugin. But my whole project works with tailwind and daisyui, I can't remove or replace it. I tried using the prose class from the @tailwindcss/typography plugin, but that didn't work either.

@layer utilities {   .oklch {     color: unset;   } }

I tried it but it didn't work. Now I realized that the problem is due to the "daisyui" plugin that I installed for tailwind. Is there a solution? @akos.one
